# How do I get rid of a Discord rate ban?

Tags: python, discord.py, replit, pycord

### Background

I ran my bot after lots of testing (because I had an annoying bug), and I was given the following error:

### Rate Ban Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 60, in <module>
    bot.run(os.getenv("password"))   File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 715, in run
    return future.result()   File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 694, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 657, in start
    await self.login(token)   File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 514, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token.strip())   File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 404, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route("GET", "/users/@me"))   File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 316, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data) discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0): <!DOCTYPE html> <!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]--> <!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]--> <!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]--> <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]--> <head> <title>Access denied | discord.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title> <meta charset="UTF-8" /> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" /> <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" /> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" /> <link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
```

### Code

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> (function(){if(document.addEventListener&&window.XMLHttpRequest&&JSON&&JSON.stringify){var e=function(a){var c=document.getElementById("error-feedback-survey"),d=document.getElementById("error-feedback-success"),b=new XMLHttpRequest;a={event:"feedback clicked",properties:{errorCode:1015,helpful:a,version:1}};b.open("POST","https://sparrow.cloudflare.com/api/v1/event");b.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");b.setRequestHeader("Sparrow-Source-Key","c771f0e4b54944bebf4261d44bd79a1e"); b.send(JSON.stringify(a));c.classList.add("feedback-hidden");d.classList.remove("feedback-hidden")};document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){var a=document.getElementById("error-feedback"),c=document.getElementById("feedback-button-yes"),d=document.getElementById("feedback-button-no");"classList"in a&&(a.classList.remove("feedback-hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!0)}),d.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!1)}))})}})(); </script>

<script defer src="https://api.radar.cloudflare.com/beacon.js"></script> <script async src='/cdn-cgi/bm/cv/669835187/api.js'></script></head> <body> <div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error hidden" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="p-0">
      <header class="mx-auto pt-10 lg:pt-6 lg:px-8 w-240 lg:w-full mb-15 antialiased">
         <h1 class="inline-block md:block mr-2 md:mb-2 font-light text-60 md:text-3xl text-black-dark leading-tight">
           <span data-translate="error">Error</span>
           <span>1015</span>
         </h1>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">Ray ID: 6f2bd4fc190d876c &bull;</span>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">2022-03-27 23:16:07 UTC</span>
        <h2 class="text-gray-600 leading-1.3 text-3xl lg:text-2xl font-light">You are being rate limited</h2>
      </header>

      <section class="w-240 lg:w-full mx-auto mb-8 lg:px-8">
          <div id="what-happened-section" class="w-1/2 md:w-full">
            <h2 class="text-3xl leading-tight font-normal mb-4 text-black-dark antialiased" data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
            <p>The owner of this website (discord.com) has banned you temporarily from accessing this website.</p>

          </div>


      </section>

      <div class="feedback-hidden py-8 text-center" id="error-feedback">
    <div id="error-feedback-survey" class="footer-line-wrapper">
        Was this page helpful?
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-yes" type="button">Yes</button>
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-no" type="button">No</button>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-success feedback-hidden" id="error-feedback-success">
        Thank you for your feedback!
    </div> </div>


      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">   <p class="text-13">
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class="font-semibold">6f2bd4fc190d876c</strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Your IP</span>: 35.225.158.222</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>
       </p> </div><!-- /.error-footer -->


    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->   </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

  <script type="text/javascript">   window._cf_translation = {};
      </script>

<script type="text/javascript">(function(){window['__CF$cv$params']={r:'6f2bd4fc190d876c',m:'eplVHNnwKuuwAS43gz7SMbi4O__zjW9eVXQm9sn7Lzg-1648422967-0-ARn+H6rOshVK+I+JcZuEwkWdsuWo5u61UZbOik2B/Y0JtczEKB0twZQT+Jc8FAX2qXzP8/11aeuUhaCeXxz7jaq5kXbkrAdxiuWdn10xzIIxMyXoHFMl5Ks3aFaRFK7JAX2j5qca4n59vNP6iTl97a8=',s:[0x340a99a83d,0xf60b769edf],}})();</script></body> </html>
```

How does one get rid of the rate ban on [Replit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replit)? I assume it would be through an IP address reset. (Note: Replit is based on Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Discord documentation states what to do and how to avoid getting banned.

Essentially, you need to check the returned API header for the information of how many request you can do before getting banned and when it is reset. See the [documentation for a full explanation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#header-format).

```
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 0
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1470173023
X-RateLimit-Reset-After: 1
X-RateLimit-Bucket: abcd1234
```

Here is your issue:

> File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 316, in request raise HTTPException(response, data) discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests

And the HTTP 429 error code is explained [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#invalid-request-limit-aka-cloudflare-bans).